# how to update every second data in my db laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

hello i have this in my one controller let say this is my customer controller

```
 $allCustomers= Customer::all();


    foreach ($allCustomers as $customer){

        // Created At In Days //
        $customer_created_at= $customer->created_at;
        $now = Carbon::now();
        $created_at_in_days = $customer_created_at->diffInDays($now);


        if ($created_at_in_days >= 0 and $created_at_in_days <= 90) {
            Customer::whereId($customer->id)->update(['collection_level' => 'Pre Collection',]);
        } elseif ($created_at_in_days >= 91 and $created_at_in_days <= 120) {
            Customer::whereId($customer->id)->update(['collection_level' => 'Collection Level 1',]);
        } elseif ($created_at_in_days >= 121 and $created_at_in_days <= 150) {
            Customer::whereId($customer->id)->update(['collection_level' => 'Collection Level 2',]);
        } elseif ($created_at_in_days >= 151) {
            Customer::whereId($customer->id)->update(['collection_level' => 'Collection Level 3',]);
        }


    }
```

this works how i want this to work but the problem i get is

that i also have a agent Controller and a client Controller where agent can work on customer accounts if that makes sense and client can see there customers

now if i copy and paste that code in all of the controller it works like it suppose to work but i would like to know how i can update that at one place without copy and pasting it in every method view and controller because now i have to copy it inside the index method in the show method in all the controllers

i just want to let it update if the created at days is past as certain day then the STATUS(or in this case the collection level)

i want it to check the records and update it every-time an agent or client is loading the view basically

i have found one other way by running a php artisan comand and let it run everyminute but i need it to check every second

```
  protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
         $schedule->command('second.update')->everyMinute();
    }


 public function handle()
    {
       $allCustomers= Customer::all();


    foreach ($allCustomers as $customer){

        // Created At In Days //
        $customer_created_at= $customer->created_at;
        $now = Carbon::now();
        $created_at_in_days = $customer_created_at->diffInDays($now);


        if ($created_at_in_days >= 0 and $created_at_in_days <= 90) {
            Customer::whereId($customer->id)->update(['collection_level' => 'Pre Collection',]);
        } elseif ($created_at_in_days >= 91 and $created_at_in_days <= 120) {
            Customer::whereId($customer->id)->update(['collection_level' => 'Collection Level 1',]);
        } elseif ($created_at_in_days >= 121 and $created_at_in_days <= 150) {
            Customer::whereId($customer->id)->update(['collection_level' => 'Collection Level 2',]);
        } elseif ($created_at_in_days >= 151) {
            Customer::whereId($customer->id)->update(['collection_level' => 'Collection Level 3',]);
        }

    echo 'Done';
}
```

Sorry for my bad English and i hope it make sense

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, you want to show the `collection_level` to the user.

Then you don't have to update the customer anytime a user view a web page. That's inefficient and unnecessary.

First, to simplify the code, lets create a custom attributes in the customer model.

```php
class Customer extends Model
{
    public function getExistingDaysAttribute()
    {
        return $this->created_at->diffInDays(now());
    }

    public function getCollectionLevelAttribute()
    {
        if ($this->existing_days >= 0 and $this->existing_days <= 90) {
            return 'Pre Collection';
        } elseif ($this->existing_days >= 91 and $this->existing_days <= 120) {
            return 'Collection Level 1';
        } elseif ($this->existing_days >= 121 and $this->existing_days <= 150) {
            return 'Collection Level 2';
        } else {
            return 'Collection Level 3';
        }
        
    }
}
```

Then, in any view, you can simply call the `collection_level` custom attribute.

```php
@foreach($customers as $customer)
    <div>{{ $customer->collection_level }}</div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: hi thank your for your answer, But i need the Collection Level to be saved in to the database is there another way like this i can use or not

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do so?

Comment: ok i am going make another example i let say i have a customer with a status active for example and if the customer created at is > 90 it need to check the database created_at field and status field and it need to update it automatically to inactivebut it need to change all the record not just check one customer field it need to check all the records this is just a example but it based on the same thing i almost want to do sorry i am really bad at explaining things